# Is it possible to have local aliases for branches?

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

My workplace uses YouTrack ticket names as branch names (e.g. MD-####). However this can look a bit factory-like in my Git desktop client and makes extra steps when returning to previously blocked work, etc.

Can i give my branches descriptive names locally for my sanity but not change the branch name on the repo?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your local branches do not need to have the same name as their corresponding remote branches. More generally, [your local branches can define an `upstream` branch](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/track-remote-upstream-branch).

Let's say you are interacting with a remote branch `MD123` but a better semantic name for it would be `nullPointerFix`.

You can create your local branch with the semantic name: `git checkout -b nullPointerFix` and then set it's upstream branch as `MD123`: `git branch -u origin/MD123`.

Now, as you work on your semantically named local branch, you can `git push` and `git pull` from the remote branch.